# CTE in From clause of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to use CTE query inside from clause of SQL Query

See this example:

```
Drop Table #Temp
Drop Table #Temp2
Create Table #Temp(name1 text, name2 text)

Insert INTO #Temp Values ('test','test')
Insert INTO #Temp Values ('test','test')

select * into #Temp2
from #Temp

Select * from #Temp2
```

Here, I am just inserting rows into temp table 'Temp2' from selecting records from Temp... this is working fine...

But my need is, have to use CTE inside from clause.. like

```
select * into #Temp2
from (;With CTE as ( Select * from #Temp) select * from CTE)
```

Please don't encourage me to separate CTE query..because, I can't control that part of query since it is being provided by other system.

```
select * into #Temp2
from ("Query Provided by Other System")
```

So the **"Query Provided by Other System"** may or may not be the CTE query.

Comment: The `with` keyword must not be prefixed with a `;`. The `;` needs to go at the **end** of the (previous) statement. The habit to prepend a `with` with a statement termination (the `;`) character only came into existence to ensure the *previous* statement was terminated correctly. It has nothing to do with the `with` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Check with below syntax, its worked for me and i hope you are looking for same:

```
With CTE as ( Select * from #Temp) 
select * into #Temp2 from CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use below query



  Create Table #Temp(name1 text, name2 text)

    Insert INTO #Temp Values ('test','test')
    Insert INTO #Temp Values ('test','test')
    GO

    With CTE as ( Select * from #Temp) 
    select * into #Temp2 from CTE

    select * from #Temp2
    GO
    Drop Table #Temp
    Drop Table #Temp2
```