# Using a CTE which calls another CTE - Incorrect syntax near ;

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a CTE which calls another CTE as follows. But I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 54 Incorrect syntax near ';'.

I cannot really see what the problem is. I checked out a bunch of other questions similar to mine & tried out the solution from those, but it won't work for some reason.

```
With SEASONALITY_AVG_REVENUE
(
    YearKey
    ,Aggregation_Key
    ,Yearly_Avg_Revenue
)   
as
(
    SELECT
        ts.YearKey,
        agg.Aggregation_Key,
        Yearly_Avg_Revenue = AVG(agg.Revenue)

    FROM 
        seasonality_custom.TIME_SERIES_INDEX ts
        INNER JOIN seasonality_custom.SEASONALITY_AGG_TIME_SERIES agg
        ON ts.TIME_SERIES_INDEX = agg.TIME_SERIES_INDEX
    GROUP BY
        ts.YearKey,
        agg.Aggregation_Key  
)
, SEASONALITY_ALL_RECS
(
    YearKey
    ,Aggregation_Key
    ,Revenue
    ,Yearly_Avg_Revenue
)   
as
(
    SELECT
        ts.YearKey,
        agg.Aggregation_Key,
        agg.Revenue,
        Yearly_Avg_Revenue = savg.Yearly_Avg_Revenue
    FROM 
        seasonality_custom.TIME_SERIES_INDEX ts
        INNER JOIN seasonality_custom.SEASONALITY_AGG_TIME_SERIES agg
        ON ts.TIME_SERIES_INDEX = agg.TIME_SERIES_INDEX
        INNER JOIN SEASONALITY_AVG_REVENUE savg
        ON ts.YearKey = savg.YearKey and agg.Aggregation_Key = savg.Aggregation_Key
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a `with` statement unless you follow it by some other statement, typically `select` but in many databases `update` and `delete` as well.

Your statement has multiple CTEs, but it doesn't have the main query part.  The error is on the semi-colon because that terminates the query.

Answer (score 1):

You really need one CTE here

```
; With SEASONALITY_AVG_REVENUE(YearKey, Aggregation_Key, Yearly_Avg_Revenue)   
AS
 (
SELECT  ts.YearKey,
        agg.Aggregation_Key,
        Yearly_Avg_Revenue = AVG(agg.Revenue)

FROM seasonality_custom.TIME_SERIES_INDEX ts INNER JOIN 
seasonality_custom.SEASONALITY_AGG_TIME_SERIES agg
ON ts.TIME_SERIES_INDEX = agg.TIME_SERIES_INDEX
GROUP BY ts.YearKey, agg.Aggregation_Key  
  )

SELECT ts.YearKey,
        agg.Aggregation_Key,
        agg.Revenue,
        Yearly_Avg_Revenue = savg.Yearly_Avg_Revenue
FROM seasonality_custom.TIME_SERIES_INDEX ts
INNER JOIN  seasonality_custom.SEASONALITY_AGG_TIME_SERIES agg
ON ts.TIME_SERIES_INDEX = agg.TIME_SERIES_INDEX
INNER JOIN SEASONALITY_AVG_REVENUE savg
ON ts.YearKey = savg.YearKey and  agg.Aggregation_Key = savg.Aggregation_Key
```

**Or**

As Gordon has mentioned CTE needs to be followed by a SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE statement.

With your current query you can simply select at the end from your second CTE and it will also return the same results but it will be an unnecessary step. Something like this..

```
;WITH CTE1 (Col1, Col2)
AS 
  (
    -- Some code here
  ),
CTE2
AS 
  (
     -- Some code here
  )
SELECT * FROM CTE2
```

Comment: The `;` should go to the _end_ of the statement, not the beginning.

Comment: CTE is the one of the only two cases  in SQL Server where it is required that the previous statement to be terminated with `;` hence a lot of SQL Developers get into the habit of starting CTEs with `;` ,  terminating statements with `;` is not a common practice among SQL Developers. hence the bad/weird habit :)

Comment: Sticking to this bad habit makes people think the keyword is `;with` and leads to all kind of strange questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078215/cte-in-from-clause-of-sql-query). Even Microsoft recommends to _terminate_ all queries with `;` (see e.g. [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons))