# Execute multiple statements and CTE in stored procedure in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I'm newish to SQL server 2012, and I'm trying to create a stored procedure that should:

1. Delete previous data from a table, based on a parameter, then
2. Insert new data on that table.

But I need to use **CTE**s for performance and other reasons (*please* don't get hung up on that, I have to, just take my word).

The CTE query works fine if it's by itself in a Stored Procedure, but I can't get the SP to work with two clauses.

I get an error when trying to create the procedure, complaining that I should use a semicolon before the CTE. If I add the semicolon, SQL Server complains about it too. It's driving me insane, **please help**!

Table where I want to delete/insert:

```
CREATE MYTABLE ( APPUSER NVARCHAR(15), DATA NVARCHAR(100) )
```

Simplified stored procedure (no semicolon):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P1 ( @SOMEUSER NVARCHAR(15), @TYPE INTEGER) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ( APPUSER=@SOMEUSER )

    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT DATA
        FROM SOURCETABLE
        WHERE ( TYPE = @TYPE )
    )
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE
    SELECT
        @SOMEUSER,
        DATA
    FROM CTE 
END
```

Error message without semicolon:

> [Error Code: 319, SQL
>   State: S1000]  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this
>   statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a
>   change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be
>   terminated with a semicolon.

Please note that even though that's a simplified version of the actual query, the error is exactly the same. I did try the above code, without any luck :(

Stored procedure with semicolon (same query as above, showing only the semicolon for brevity):

```
(...)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ( APPUSER=@SOMEUSER ); /* Semicolon */

    WITH CTE AS (    
(...)
```

Error with semicolon:

> [Error Code: 102, SQL State: 42000]  Incorrect syntax near ')'.

I tried enclosing the DELETE clause in it's own transaction, that didn't work either, always get one of the two errors.

Any pointers will be very appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: Put a semicolon before `WITH`. Like this: `;WITH`.

Comment: @wewesthemenace - Both are eqivalent

Comment: Your second query looks fine. If possible post the complete query

Comment: Oh right. Didn't notice that! sorry.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks. I tried like this: `CREATE PROCEDURE P1 ( @SOMEUSER NVARCHAR(15), @TYPE INTEGER) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ( APPUSER=@SOMEUSER )
    
    ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT DATA
        FROM SOURCETABLE
        WHERE ( TYPE = @TYPE )
    )
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE
    SELECT
        @SOMEUSER,
        DATA
    FROM CTE 
END` same error _Incorrect syntax near ')'._

Comment: You should post your complete query. The one you gave does not produce an error on my local machine.

Comment: @wewesthemenace: actually you should put a `;` **after** each statement: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yup I understood that. However, as the OP pointed out, that does not solve his problem. Maybe the problem is caused by the other part of his query we do not know of.

Comment: I think you should look for a mismatched paren.

Comment: @wewesthemenace: advocating the use of `;with` makes people think that `;with` is a *single* "keyword" and results in stuff like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078215/cte-in-from-clause-of-sql-query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I completely agree with you. I merely suggested it for a quick fix. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What stumps me is that I can save and run the stored procedure with the CTE query by itself. If I add any other statement, even a simple SELECT * that's when SQL Server complains about the semicolon. I don't think the query is the problem, maybe there is a setting I'm not aware of that is causing a conflict?

Comment: @RaiderofthelostBBS, disregard my previous suggestion. `;` is a terminator, not a "beginator" so this must be put **after** each statement rather than before.

Comment: @RaiderofthelostBBS, if you terminate all statements before the `CTE` with a semicolon, the SP should not error out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have something strange going on because the following works for me:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P1 ( @SOMEUSER NVARCHAR(15), @TYPE INTEGER) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [Table_1] WHERE ( [lname]=@SOMEUSER );

    WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT [fname], [lname]
        FROM [Table_1]
        WHERE ( [ID] = @TYPE )
    )
    INSERT INTO [Table_1]
    SELECT top 1
        @SOMEUSER,
        [lname],
        @TYPE
    FROM CTE 
END
```

Check your environment

A CTE is just syntax - it does not help performance

Comment: CTE helps performance when using it directs the server to use specific indexes, or when you can reduce the scope of a query :) 

I never actually found what is wrong so I ended up deleting outside of the SP as a separate step but I selected your answer because evertying I read agrees that it _should_ work. Must be a problem with the front-end or the server itself. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

You need to put a ';' before 'With' keyword, your code look like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P1 ( @SOMEUSER NVARCHAR(15), @TYPE INTEGER) AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE ( APPUSER=@SOMEUSER )

    ;WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT DATA
        FROM SOURCETABLE
        WHERE ( TYPE = @TYPE )
    )
    INSERT INTO MYTABLE
    SELECT
        @SOMEUSER,
        DATA
    FROM CTE 
END
```

As a thumb rule for CTE, always start with a semicolon if you have any executable statement above your CTE.

Comment: As a rule of thumb you should **end** each statement with a semicolon: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Answer (score 1):

For complete clarity of the points raised by others, this excerpt form [the MSDN documentation on CTE's in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms175972.aspx) is an essential note for usage of CTE's:

> •When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the
>   statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.

As also noted, it is best practice to either:

- Develop the habit of ending all SQL statements with a semicolon; or
- Learn and memorize all required semicolons, such as here, and preface all these constructs with one.

I prefer the  first, but I have seen competent developers who prefer the second.