# INSERT INTO WITH Common Table Expression - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have figured out how to recursively find all employees reporting up to a certain manager using Common Table Expressions (Thanks to StackOverflow!).

This is the code that works for me:

```
WITH MyCTE AS 
(
    SELECT [WWID] FROM [x500]..[WorkerPublicExtended] 
    WHERE [MgrWWID] = '10624529' AND ([StatCode] = 'A') AND ([BadgeType] = 'BB') 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [WorkerPublicExtended].[WWID] FROM [x500]..[WorkerPublicExtended] 
        INNER JOIN MyCTE ON [WorkerPublicExtended].[MgrWWID] = MyCTE.WWID 
    WHERE [WorkerPublicExtended].[MgrWWID] IS NOT NULL 
        AND ([BadgeType] = 'BB') AND ([StatCode] = 'A')
) 

SELECT *, 'MGR+10624529' AS [source] FROM MyCTE
```

This works perfectly. But if I try to insert this into another table (which is the ultimate goal) I can't find any syntactical variation of this code that doesn't throw one or more errors.  Can someone help me put these together?

```
INSERT INTO [LTDtraining].[dbo].[pop00001]
WITH MyCTE AS 
(
    SELECT [WWID] FROM [x500]..[WorkerPublicExtended] 
    WHERE [MgrWWID] = '10624529' AND ([StatCode] = 'A') AND ([BadgeType] = 'BB') 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [WorkerPublicExtended].[WWID] FROM [x500]..[WorkerPublicExtended] 
        INNER JOIN MyCTE ON [WorkerPublicExtended].[MgrWWID] = MyCTE.WWID 
    WHERE [WorkerPublicExtended].[MgrWWID] IS NOT NULL 
        AND ([BadgeType] = 'BB') AND ([StatCode] = 'A')
) 

SELECT *, 'MGR+10624529' AS [source] FROM MyCTE
```

It is throwing errors like:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MyCTE'.

Or the ever-popular

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

And if I insert the suggested semicolon, it responds with

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ';'.

So it makes me think I don't know what I'm doing here, and neither does SQL.

Comment: Try putting the insert statement after the CTE (e.g 'WITH CTE AS (...) INSERT...'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error can easily be fixed by moving the `INSERT` statement down below the `WITH` like so:

```
WITH MyCTE AS 
(
    SELECT [WWID] FROM [x500]..[WorkerPublicExtended] 
    WHERE [MgrWWID] = '10624529' AND ([StatCode] = 'A') AND ([BadgeType] = 'BB') 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT [WorkerPublicExtended].[WWID] FROM [x500]..[WorkerPublicExtended] 
        INNER JOIN MyCTE ON [WorkerPublicExtended].[MgrWWID] = MyCTE.WWID 
    WHERE [WorkerPublicExtended].[MgrWWID] IS NOT NULL 
        AND ([BadgeType] = 'BB') AND ([StatCode] = 'A')
)

INSERT INTO [LTDtraining].[dbo].[pop00001] 
SELECT *, 'MGR+10624529' AS [source] FROM MyCTE
```

Comment: The semicolon should go to the **end** of each statement: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree, but it's hard to get into the habit of doing that lol.

Comment: By sticking to this way of writing it, people think that a CTE is started using the keyword `;WITH` which leads to questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23078215/330315

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, but since we don't know if Richard's code had any code being called before it (or it's probably safe to assume no since he said the top query worked for him), I added the semi-colon for safety precautions. I'll just remove it and remember to add the semicolon at the end next time :).

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Odom!  That did the trick!  Very pleased!  :-)